# How to make the checkboxes work in ie 7 and 8

Tags: html, css, image, forms

Basically in the form when you click on the image, it should also check the box. This works in in all browsers but IE7 and IE8. Anyone have any ideas?

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest1" id="interest1" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest2" id="interest2" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest3" id="interest3" value="x"></p>   
<p align="center"><label for="interest1"><img src="/images/interest1.jpg" width="152" height="152" alt="" /></label>
<label for="interest2"><img src="/images/interest2.jpg" width="152" height="152" alt="" /></label>
<label for="interest3"><img src="/images/interest.jpg" width="152" height="152" alt="" /></label></P><!-- code making checkbox be an image-->
</form>
```

Comment: I can confirm this in IE9 using IE8 and IE7 mode.

Comment: Have you tried adding `alt` text to the images? (You should anyway for screen reader users.)

Comment: adding alts changes nothing, but a good catch none the less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that IE < 9 doesn't like subnodes (non-input) in a label. A workaround is to set the images as the background of the label and making the label be `inline-block` so you can set its size. Tested in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/K9FEk/8/

**CSS**

```
label {
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
}

#label-interest1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/36fa212d5215d9f282033375834ba0c0?s=120&d=identicon&r=PG);
    width: 152px;
    height:152px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form>    
  <input type="checkbox" name="interest1" id="interest1" value="x">        
  <p align="center">    
    <label id="label-interest1" for="interest1"></label>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is but this CSS made it work for me in IE8 and IE7 mode using IE9.

```
label {
    display:inline-block; /* "block" would also work */
}
img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K9FEk/3/

It may be because the image's space on the page was expanding out of the `display:inline` styled `<label>`, or that it was "above" the label, hijacking the click event.

Comment: this worked for me in 7, but not 8 as wird as that is. any hints?

Comment: Ah you're right IE8 still flakes out. Let me try something... EDIT: Damn, I can't figure it out for IE8 - the checkbox lights up a little when I hover, but clicking the image does nothing. Sorry but I gotta run, I'll leave this post here for now in case it gives anyone an idea.